# how to alter the range of values of a plot generated by spectrogram function

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, wavelet, haar-wavelet

In the below posted image, I am trying to get `TFR` using `STFT`. In the code posted, I specified the paramerter `T = 0:.001:1;` and when I modify it to be, for an example, `T = 0:.001:2;` the values range on the horizontal axis of the plot changes, despite it is labelled `Frequency`.

Now, I want to change the ranges of values of the horizontal and the vertical axes on the shown plot. How can I do that?

NOTE: the code used to generate the shown plot is:

```
T = 0:.001:1;
spectrogram(x4,128,50,NFFT);
```

**CODE**:

```
% Time specifications:
 Fs = 8000;                       % samples per second
 dt = 1/Fs;                       % seconds per sample
 StopTime = 1;                    % seconds
  t = (0:dt:StopTime-dt);             % seconds

  t1 = (0:dt:.25);
   t2 = (.25:dt:.50);
  t3 = (.5:dt:.75);
  t4 = (.75:dt:1);

  %two freqs. = abs(f1 - f2), that's why, x1 is plotted with 2 freqs.
  x1 = (10)*sin(2*pi*30*t1);
  x2 = (10)*sin(2*pi*60*t2) + x1;
  x3 = (10)*sin(2*pi*90*t3) + x2;
  x4 = (10)*sin(2*pi*120*t4) + x3;
  %x5 = (10) * sin(2*pi*5*t5);
  %x6 = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5;

  NFFT = 2 ^ nextpow2(length(t));     % Next power of 2 from length of y
  Y    = fft(x3, NFFT);
  f    = Fs / 2 * linspace(0, 1, NFFT/2 + 1);
  figure;
  plot(f(1:200), 2 * abs( Y( 1:200) ) );

  T = 0:.001:1;
  spectrogram(x4,10,9,31);
   axis(get(gcf,'children'), [0, 1,0,100]);

% Plot the signal versus time:
figure;
xlabel('time (in seconds)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('non-stationary Signal versus Time');

 hold on
 plot(t1,x1,'r');
plot(t2,x2,'g');
plot(t3,x3,'b');
plot(t4,x4,'black');
%plot(t5,x5,'y');
%plot(t, x6,'black');
legend('x1 = (10)*sin(2*pi*15*t1) + (10)*sin(2*pi*8*t1)', 'x2 = (10)*sin(2*pi*25*t2) + x1',   
'x3 = (10)*sin(2*pi*50*t3) + x2', 'x4 = (10)*sin(2*pi*75*t4) + x3', ...
'Location',  'SouthWest');
```

**image**

[image]

**new Result_1**
[image]

Comment: @Schorsch i posted the code

Comment: If I copy/paste that code, it tells me that `T` is not being used. Changing `T` has **no** impact on the plot. Please consider clarifying your question.

Comment: The problem behind the white "stripe" between `0.967` and `1.0` is because in your code, you set the 4th input to [`spectrogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) to `31`. However, the documentation specifies this as `the FFT length` - which in your case is `8192`.

Comment: @Schorsch ok, in my code i specified that "Y = fft(x4, NFFT);" and after reading your suggestion i changed the spectrogram parameters to be "spectrogram(x4,10,9,length(y));" but now when i run matlab does not accept this parameter

Comment: @Schorsch ok i solved that issue, i just specified the NFFT without "length" as the 4th parameter to the spectrogram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Idea:** get the `axis` the was used to plot the spectrogram and set its properties accordingly. For example, supposing you'd want to restrict the *x* range to [0, 0.5] and *y* to [100, 200], then:

```
%'old code here'
%' . . . '
spectrogram(x4,128,50,NFFT);

%'new code here'
axis(get(gcf,'children'), [0, 0.5, 100, 200]);
```

**Explanation:** The added one-liner `get`s the child handle from the current figure `gcf` (wich is assumed to be created by `spectrogram`), then sets it's range to `[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]` via `axis` call.

**Nota Bene:** I assume that you just need to *re-scale* the axis, not *re-compute* the `spectrogram` for different data.

Also I assume the spectrogram *doesn't share* its figure with other axes.

Also, *extending* the axis range rather than *restricting* it might not give you the expected results (in a word: is ugly).

Comment: thanks for the idea. kindly please have a look at the new posted image after applying your suggestion. 1- why the interval on the horizontal axis which is slightly before 1 is in white? 2- how can i read this plot?is a correct representation of STFT?

Comment: @rmaik 1 - Would you mind sharing the range modification code that you used? I don't want to guess it, as it's simpler to look at it. 2 - Well, you read it like a spectrogram. :-) The color of an (x,y) "dot" on the graph gives you the power of a certain harmonic (x axis) calculated by STFT at a certain moment (y axis).

Comment: regarding reading the spectrogram, from 0-.25 seconds i should have a signal with 30*.25 peaks, because it is 30 cycle/sec. but iin the spectrogram the rang on the horiz.axis from 0->.25 has many corresponding readings on the vertical axis as if from 0->.25 secs. there are signals of many frequencies. One more thing, after i changed the range of the axese as you earlierly suggestd, now i want  to change the name of the vertical axis? how can i do that please

Comment: @rmaik For the spectrogram reading part: you add `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`, and not concatenate them; your signal is just quarter of second long instead of a second. So you don't have different spectra at different times (which is visible in the graph). I think it would be a good idea for you to state clearly what is the purpose of the code and what you'd expect as result in your posting, so we avoid prolonged Q/A sessions in comments.

Comment: @rmaik For y-labeling y an axis: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylabel.html and check the `ylabel(ax,___)`. Check also the formatting and annotation help: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/formatting-and-annotation.html